# How to add custom icon theme support to android launcher

Tags: java, android, themes, android-launcher

I am working on an android launcher, I want to add icon theme support to the launcher.
 *The launcher uses launcher-2 source code*. **How to add theme support for Icons?**

Answer (score 1):

You have to traverse through the appfilter.xml file in icon pack and set drawable for the curresponding package name defined in the appfilter.xml file ... use XmlPullParser class to manipulate xml data....

here is a basic idea...

```
Resources resources = packageManager.getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
int xmlResId = resources.getIdentifier("appfilter", "xml", packageName);

if (xmlResId != 0) {
    XmlPullParser xpp = resources.getXml(xmlResId);
    // manipulate data using xpp
}
```

Some old icon packs has a different xml structure some has appfilter.xml in asset folder ...

Comment: sabeersas thank you for the response can you please elaborate a bit I am still learning android programing where do I put the code snipit you shared above?